# UWP NavigationView.HeaderTemplate not working on 1903

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

i have the following main view

```
<NavigationView AlwaysShowHeader="True">
    <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Trxto" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
    <NavigationView.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Content" />
    </NavigationView.Content>
</NavigationView>
```

If i run this while targeting Windows 10 1803 i can see the header, but if i
change the target version to 1903 it doesn't show up....

So, I'm lost here, any help would be appreciate

Comment: You have not set header property for `NavigationView`. 
`<NavigationView AlwaysShowHeader="True" Header="Test">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP NavigationView.HeaderTemplate not working on 1903

The problem is that you just implement `HeaderTemplate`, but you have not set `Header` property. the `HeaderTemplate` will not render.

```
NavigationView. <NavigationView AlwaysShowHeader="True" Header="Test">
```

Comment: That does the trick!, but this does look like a workaround.... Anyway thanks !